# OPC server create model information from existing nodeset file

Tags: opc-ua, opc

I have a task that is create an opc server and instantaneously read data from an injection molding cnc machine with opc client. I have read a lot of documentation and came to a conclusion which I need a model information xml file and create c# classes with a compiler according to the model information file.

I have come across with OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset repository which has Node Id's that plastic rubber devices shares.(I assume that)  There is also a Opc.Ua.PlasticsRubber.IMM2MES.NodeSet2.xml file which is the final ingredient that model compiler produces.

Also I assume when I point my opc server address to the molding cnc device, I will read or machine push data with those spesific nodeIds.(I might be awfully wrong here)

Now the confusion begins here; In the Opc.Ua.PlasticsRubber.IMM2MES.NodeSet2.xml, there are some nodeIds presented. Is the data presented by the molding device published with that nodeIds or those id's are just a unique key for model file? Also when I try to create model information file, nodeId's are different. Is nodeIds should match with the nodeset2.xml?

In the end, I want to read lets say machine status data which nodeId is 5006, should match the model information file which I created in order to get data?

Thank  you.

Answer (score 0):

The nodeset in the Companion Specification usually contains only Types (such as ObjectTypes, VariableTypes, etc.) and sometimes an object that serves as an entry point (e.g. DeviceSet of DI). To use these types, you need to create an instance of an object in the address space of your OPC UA server. For example, in your case, the instance might be of the IMM_MES_InterfaceType. The nodes of your instance will have different nodeIds than the types.

As an OPC UA client, you should use the BrowsePath (and the browse service) to locate the correct node in the address space. Once you have the nodeId, you can read or write data from it. In the first step, you can use a generic OPC UA client such as UaExpert for browsing, but it is recommended to implement browsing in your own application. This will allow you to connect to other machines with the same interface.

In think your BrowsePath for the MachineStatus should something like this:

```
Objects.DeviceSet.IMM_<Manufacturer>_<SerialNumber>.MachineStatus
```

An example of an  plastic rubber devices [should be here](https://github.com/umati/Sample-Server-node-opcua)